# Incorrect result after addition within a function

Tags: java

I have a java program that does not return the correct answer and I cannot figure out why. here's the code:

```
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a =5;
        doubleNumbers(a);
        System.out.println(" 5 doubled is:"+a);
    }

    private static void doubleNumbers(int a) {
        a = 5*2;
    }
}
```

It is my first java program after helloWorld.

Comment: Make sure you're following along in your book; it should discuss return values etc.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. It works correctly with my new code. What should I do with this question now? delete it? and how do they decide who gets points for answering? sorry for the noob questions, this is my first time here.

Comment: It's a great question, actually. You might consider to change the title, so it's easier to find for someone else. Other than that, you should read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq as proposed before.

Comment: Does the new title sound ok? and I am a little confused on how you get your question upvoted to be seen by more people. it sounds hard to do.. for example: there are seven answers but only 1 upvote?

Comment: I have now changed the title (not to include the answer, but the symptoms) and reindented the code (Because that makes it more likely to be read, by someone), but it has to be reviewed by a moderator first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First you should change the doubleNumbers method to return something, next you should change the print statement to where it is printing the returned value.

for example(in pseudo code, so you have to think about it!):

```
method doCalculation{
....
return calculated answer
}

main{
....
Print(doCalculation)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Java is [pass-by-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value), which means that the variables passed to a function are not changed outside of it.

As this is homework I will not show you the solution, but just tell you to return the value of the calculation.

Comment: All primitives are pass-by-value, but all other objects are pass-by-reference.

Comment: @twall: Wrong.  Everything in Java is passed by value, but the _references_ are passed by value; the objects are never passed at all.  There's a difference.

Answer (score 3):

you're not returning anything from your method

change it to

```
 private static int doubleNumbers(int a) { 
return a * 2; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the method `doubleNumbers` to return the result of the calculation, so it would look something like this:

```
private static void doubleNumbers(int a) {
    return a*2;
}
```

And then change the lines in the main method:

```
int a = 5;
a = doubleNumbers(a);
```

Also, `doubleNumbers` would only ever return 10 in the original implementation. You need to use the `a` variable you passed in, as the above code shows.

Answer (score 0):

primitive types in Java passed by value not by reference.
You need Object-type to pass it by reference
try this:

```
 private static void doubleNumbers(Integer a) {
a = a*2;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 obvious problems:

1. You do not assign the return value of `doubleNumbers()` to any variable.
2. `doubleNumbers()` does not return a value (replace `void`with `int`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class hello {


     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
       int a =5;
       a = doubleNumbers(a);

       System.out.println(" 5 doubled is:"+a);

     }

     private static int doubleNumbers(int a) {
       return a*2;
     }

}
```

Each variable has a context, by default limited to the function which uses it.

Your `a` in the `doubleNumbers()` function isn't the same as the first one.

You need to return the result, and assign it to your original `a` variable

Answer (score 0):

A better way will be to change double Numbers() method from `void` to `int` so it can be returnable and also instead of printing only `a`, rather print the method as now it will be doubling the `a`.
I've also added Scanner so the program don't just double 5 but any number you enter.

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int a = myScn.nextInt();
    //doubleNumbers(a);
    System.out.println(a+ " doubled is:"+doubleNumbers(a));

  }

  private static int doubleNumbers(int a) {
    int x = a*2;
        return x;
  }
}
```